# Modules like Scroll Reveal

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm looking for a module like [Scroll Reveal](https://www.drupal.org/project/scrollreveal). The functionality is quite simple, when a user enters a viewport, content will be displayed using jquery effects.

The outstanding issues for the aforementioned module imply that it appears to be broken, according to the issue queue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please make your question clearer, do you mean there are open issues in the module's issue queue that render the module unusable?

Comment: Have you tried the module? It may be that is just not working for those few users that have posted an issue.

Comment: Most (all?!) modules have issues in the issue queue, you should give it a try and if it doesn't fit your needs try something else and if you find a new bug report it, that way the module will improve.

Comment: I thought the first sentence of my question summed up everything I was looking for. Cannot get much clearer than that. I even added the exact functionality I was looking for in the second sentence. Pre-empting the "why don't you just use the referenced module" comments was the reason for the second paragraph. Yes, I had tried it and, like many others, found it to not function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced issues with the module. I think that the module has not kept pace with the scrollReveal library development.

So file a bug report, or just add the functionality to your theme yourself.

Add the library in template_preprocess_html, and then add `data-sr` to any element you want the functionality on.

Comment: I suspect you are correct. Thanks for the pointer. I'll take your suggestion for a spin and see how it goes.